# How can I split a 16-children HTML elements into 16x1 / 8x2 / 4x4 according to the parent width automatically?

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar which contains 16 links.

On desktop screens, I want the 16 links be there in a row.

And when the window gets smaller, I want the 16 links to split into two lines with both 8 links.

And then when the window width gets very narrow, I want the 16 links split into 4x4 grid.

What can I do in CSS? Currently I have to hard code the width of the parent, which sounds very difficult to maintain or update in the future.

```css
div {padding:.5em;margin:1em;border: 1px solid #000}

div#test1 {width:550px}
nav a {width:60px; background:#ff0; text-align:center;padding:.5em}
nav {display:flex; gap:.5em; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content:center}

div#test2 {width:500px}


div#test3 {width:400px}


div#test4 {width:680px}
```

```html
<h3>This is NOT good:</h3>
<div id="test1">

<nav>
  <a>br3f</a>
  <a>dfee</a>
  <a>xfef</a>
  <a>33fv</a>
  <a>vef3</a>
  <a>f3rr</a>
  <a>ber3</a>
  <a>b4t3</a>
  <a>nyjk</a>
  <a>dsfj</a>
  <a>rg4h</a>
  <a>nlkg</a>
  <a>gvre</a>
  <a>berg</a>
  <a>grgg</a>
  <a>gr4g</a>
</nav>

</div>



<h3>This is NOT good:</h3>
<div id="test2">

<nav>
  <a>br3f</a>
  <a>dfee</a>
  <a>xfef</a>
  <a>33fv</a>
  <a>vef3</a>
  <a>f3rr</a>
  <a>ber3</a>
  <a>b4t3</a>
  <a>nyjk</a>
  <a>dsfj</a>
  <a>rg4h</a>
  <a>nlkg</a>
  <a>gvre</a>
  <a>berg</a>
  <a>grgg</a>
  <a>gr4g</a>
</nav>

</div>


<h3>This is good:</h3>
<div id="test3">

<nav>
  <a>br3f</a>
  <a>dfee</a>
  <a>xfef</a>
  <a>33fv</a>
  <a>vef3</a>
  <a>f3rr</a>
  <a>ber3</a>
  <a>b4t3</a>
  <a>nyjk</a>
  <a>dsfj</a>
  <a>rg4h</a>
  <a>nlkg</a>
  <a>gvre</a>
  <a>berg</a>
  <a>grgg</a>
  <a>gr4g</a>
</nav>

</div>

<h3>This is good:</h3>
<div id="test4">

<nav>
  <a>br3f</a>
  <a>dfee</a>
  <a>xfef</a>
  <a>33fv</a>
  <a>vef3</a>
  <a>f3rr</a>
  <a>ber3</a>
  <a>b4t3</a>
  <a>nyjk</a>
  <a>dsfj</a>
  <a>rg4h</a>
  <a>nlkg</a>
  <a>gvre</a>
  <a>berg</a>
  <a>grgg</a>
  <a>gr4g</a>
</nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grid` layout for this. I have added media queries for `max-width:500px` and `max-width:1200px` yo can use any pixel value you want for your ** screen-break-points** and add more media queries if you want. `repeat(4, 1fr)` simply saves time writing `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` , so don't be confused by that. Check this link to learn some basics about grid-layout: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

```css
nav {
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  gap: .25rem;
}

nav a {
  width: 60px;
  background: #ff0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em
}

/*for laptop/medium-desktop */
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  nav {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
/* 0- 500px screen-size for mobile/tablet */
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  nav {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Navbbar :</h3>
<nav>
  <a>br3f</a>
  <a>dfee</a>
  <a>xfef</a>
  <a>33fv</a>
  <a>vef3</a>
  <a>f3rr</a>
  <a>ber3</a>
  <a>b4t3</a>
  <a>nyjk</a>
  <a>dsfj</a>
  <a>rg4h</a>
  <a>nlkg</a>
  <a>gvre</a>
  <a>berg</a>
  <a>grgg</a>
  <a>gr4g</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a flex-box or grid to wrap all of these nav links. Then in your css, you can use [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/) to make the layout change according to screen width.

I recommend you learn about this as it is a very powerful tool to making responsive websites.

Comment: Your answer should provide a solution and not just a suggestion like "go learn about how to make websites". You also need to explain why and how  your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

You said you want it based on the parent width so media query won't really help you. You either need a container query or use the below solution.

Resize the div to see the result. I have a detailed article about this trick: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/

```css
nav {
  /* first breakpoint*/
  --w1:1200px;
  --n:16;
  /* second breakpoint*/
  --w2:800px;
  --m:8;
  /* third breakpoint*/
  --w3:400px;
  --p:4;

  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    repeat(auto-fill,
      minmax(clamp(clamp(clamp(  
            (100% - (var(--n) - 1)*.5em)/var(--n),
              (var(--w1) - 100%)*1000,
            100%/(var(--m) + 1)), 
              (var(--w2) - 100%)*1000,
            100%/(var(--p) + 1)), 
              (var(--w3) - 100%)*1000,
            100%), 1fr));
  gap: .5em;
}

div {padding:.5em;margin:1em;border: 1px solid #000;overflow: hidden; resize: horizontal;}

nav a {background:#ff0; text-align:center;padding:.5em}
```

```html
<div>
 <nav>
  <a>br3f</a>
  <a>dfee</a>
  <a>xfef</a>
  <a>33fv</a>
  <a>vef3</a>
  <a>f3rr</a>
  <a>ber3</a>
  <a>b4t3</a>
  <a>nyjk</a>
  <a>dsfj</a>
  <a>rg4h</a>
  <a>nlkg</a>
  <a>gvre</a>
  <a>berg</a>
  <a>grgg</a>
  <a>gr4g</a>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, sorry I should mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: It is specifically mentioned that it is supposed to be according to the screen-size. @AGamePlayer tried to set the parent width to make it work not the other way around. No need to use such complicated css logic.

Comment: @AniketPandey read the title of the question again

Comment: Read the complete description